# How can I set the application information on a session using the Oracle thin JDBC driver?

Tags: oracle, session, jdbc, inspection

I'd like to change the application information that is shown when inspecting
Oracle 10g sessions using the Oracle Enterprise Manager application:

```
Application Information  
  Program       'my program'  
  Module        'something'  
  Command       UNKNOWN
```

I'm using the JDBC thin driver to connect, and I have to admit I'd rather not
use the OCI driver if at all possible.  Can I do this with the thin driver, and
if so, how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DBMS_APPLICATION_INFO should take care of that:

http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14258/d_appinf.htm

Answer (score 1):

use the appropriate method within the DBMS_APPLICATION_INFO package (.SET_ACTION, .SET_CLIENT_INFO, .SET_MODULE

Comment: uh... at risk of coming off as dense, what is the "DBMS_APPLICATION_INFO" package?